# Submit X-editable table via form without ajax not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

Here is what I have tried `http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/63/` for editing my table without ajax. I want to post my form once whole editing is done to a servlet.But it turns out, once I hit on submit button, whole edited data is gone. My Servlet still gets old value. Is there any way out ? Please help me , I am kind of stuck here. Looks like somehow data is not getting saved in DOM ,because when I check view source edited data is not getting saved.
Here is my form

```
<form method="post" action="ProcessTableDataServlet">
 <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tr><th>#</th><th>name</th><th>age</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-pk="1">Mike</a></td>
            <td>21</td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-pk="2">John</a></td>
            <td>28</td>       
        </tr>        
     </table>    
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Is there any solution to my problem?  Please help me